# Split text file to multiple files by specific string or line number using python

Tags: python, string, split

Want to split text file based on specific text(string) but unable to find solution so first collect line number of in which that string is existed and try to split file.

here is the code for collecting lines form text file.

```
file1 = open("textfile_1.txt", "r")

string1 = 'Weight Total'

flag = 0
index = 0
fl = 1

Spl_Lines = []
for line in file1:  
    index += 1 

    if string1 in line:
        Spl_Lines.append(index)
print(Spl_Lines)
```

As result getting line numbers in which "Weight Total" is mentioned.

**Out put:**
[350, 850, 1123, 1640, 1810, 2250]

Now want to split the text file from the listed lines so I tried below code but it didn't work. struggling to split text file with the specific word string matching.

```
lines = file1.readlines()
# print(lines) getting blank
for i in Spl_Lines:
    with open('E'+str(fl)+".txt",'w') as file:
        for line in lines[i]:
            file.write(line)
        fl += 1
```

I tried this but not working, how to split a text file into multiple files by specific string or listed lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a single pass of the input file as follows:

```
key = 'Weight Total'

outfile = None
fileno = 0
lineno = 0

with open('textfile_1.txt') as infile:
    while line := infile.readline():
        lineno += 1
        if outfile is None:
            fileno += 1
            outfile = open(f'E{fileno}.txt', 'w')
        outfile.write(line)
        if key in line:
            print(f'"{key}" found in line {lineno}')
            outfile.close()
            outfile = None
if outfile:
    outfile.close()
```

**Note:**

This assumes that any line containing the key is to be included in the output file(s)

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Albert , but in main file string "Weight Total" get only 51 times but split txt files generated 154. sorry, I can't share the file but can you please check with some dummy text for above code.

Comment: @nirav.sos I have tested this. The code presented will create one file for each occurrence of 'Weight Total'. Maybe you had some E*.txt files left over from your previous code. I suggest you delete all output files and try again. If you're working on a Unix type system try this:- grep "Weight Total" textfile_1.txt | wc -l

Comment: I was working on remote server but to check your code I download the file to local system and test which is first time in my system, don't know what happened but same thing happens with my colleague's system, 154 file was generated.
May be because of improper data "multiple white spaces and blank rows" text file.

Comment: is it possible to remove more than single space first?

Comment: @nirav.sos Did you grep the file to count the occurrences? Maybe 'Weight Total' occurs in places that you didn't expect

Comment: yes, I manually check the total count, till date, we are manually processing this text file and currently, we try to automate with python.

Comment: @nirav.sos Please show the output of *grep "Weight Total" textfile_1.txt | wc -l*

Comment: @nirav.sos Small change to the code to output where the key is observed. Try it

Comment: Sorry my bad, your code is correct source location count is 51 but issue in file export in which we get "Weight Total"  153 times, your code is working fine with original file.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split the string on your `string1`, and then append the text back?

```py
file1 = open("textfile_1.txt", "r")
string1 = 'Weight Total'
text = file1.read()

text_splitted = [i + string1 for i in text.split(string1)]
```

Comment: Remember to close the file, or use a context manager.